# Sort NSArray of NSobjects that contain NSNumber variables

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsnumber, nsobject

I have an NSArray of Object Classes which consist of two textfields. I would like to sort these objects in ascending order, I have done this with NSDictionary objects before however I have now changed then to an Object Class that I have made so I dont really know how to compare the values to get the sorted array.

The object variables are **NSNumbers** but contain only number values, which I think will effect things.

This is how I was sorted the NSDictionary value with my old code.

```
 NSArray *tempSortedItemsArray = [installArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                            @[[NSSortDescriptor
                               sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first" ascending:YES],
                            [NSSortDescriptor
                             sortDescriptorWithKey:@"second" ascending:YES]]];

    sortedItemsArray = [tempSortedItemsArray mutableCopy];
    tempSortedItemsArray = nil;
```

So if I have an array of object like this

(first / second)

```
2 1
0 0 
1 0
1 1
2 2
2 0
3 0
```

if would sort like this

```
0 0
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
2 2 
3 0
```

any help adjusting this for NSObject class with NSNumber variables first and second would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Why would you want to sort an array of objects containing text fields?  Why doesn't the custom object contain just the data?  I think you are doing something strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[arr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
   NSString *first=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",obj1.num1.intValue,obj1.num2.intValue];
 NSString *second=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",obj2.num1.intValue,obj2.num2.intValue];
    return [first compare:second options:NSNumericSearch];

}];
```

Comment: Whoops, the Object variables are actually NSNumbers, could you please check out my updated questiong?

Comment: This didnt quite work I think I wasnt explicit enough in my question.. its close it sortes the first var... but not the second var as in my example of the sorted objects.. ill keep trying

Comment: ahh i see you updated as i was posting my last comment will test now!

Comment: Why would you use string comparison here and not just compare the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other sort methods of `NSArray` such as:

- `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`
- `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`
- `sortedArrayUsingComparator:`

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some example usage of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

Given an Object that works like this:

```
@interface Object : NSObject

@property (copy) NSNumber *first;
@property (copy) NSNumber *second;

+(Object *)objectWithWithFirst:(NSNumber *)first second:(NSNumber *)second;

@end


@implementation Object

+(Object *)objectWithWithFirst:(NSNumber *)first second:(NSNumber *)second {
    Object *object = [[Object alloc] init];
    object.first = first;
    object.second = second;
    return object;
}


-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", _first, _second];
}

@end
```

Your could sort with

```
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Object *obj1, Object *obj2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [obj2.second compare:obj2.second];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        result = [obj1.first compare:obj2.first];
    return result;
}];
```

Example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *array = @[
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@2 second:@1],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@0 second:@0],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@1 second:@0],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@1 second:@1],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@2 second:@2],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@2 second:@0],
                           [Object objectWithWithFirst:@3 second:@0]
                           ];

        NSLog(@"%@", array);

        NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Object *obj1, Object *obj2) {
            NSComparisonResult result = [obj2.second compare:obj2.second];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
                result = [obj1.first compare:obj2.first];
            return result;
        }];

        NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which will work perfectly on your sample data. Of course, you could put the comparator code directly into your Object class - cleaning thins up even more.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom class has the properties `first` and `second` then the code you've posted will just work.

`NSNumber`s already know how to compare themselves to other numbers. `NSSortDesvriptor`s work with any object that implements the reading part of key-value coding. All `NSObject` subclasses automatically do so for any property that follows ordinary conventions. `@property`s follow ordinary conventions.